# App Crashing while Interacting with it Using Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

My app crashes when I am interacting with it in certain way. I am not understanding why this is happening. I am unable to write my problem in words so I have uploaded a 1.43 minutes video on YouTube, please see it from https://youtu.be/dmaD0h7tzVc. I hope you have seen the video and understood my problem. I am using Toast to see what values are coming from different fragments.

Now my main activity which is calling all the fragments is below

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    actionBar = getActionBar();
    mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    for (String tab_name : tabs) {
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name)
                .setTabListener(this));
    }
    viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
}
```

Comment: Post the full logcat of the crash please.

Comment: @Vucko i am not having my code currently, it in my work place. Its showing me `java.io.nullpointerexception`

Comment: I'd place my bets on this line: `actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);` since `getActionBar()` might return null.

Comment: @Vucko i tried to change that also, but then too the app crashes as i swips it for first time, but i'll check whether `getActionBar()` is returning null or not.

Comment: try to call getSupportActionBar() instead of getActionBar() method.

Answer (score 0):

If `actionbar=getActionBar();` gets null means change to `actionbar=getSupportActionBar();`
And instead of import `android.support.v4.app.ActionBar` use import `android.support.v7.app.ActionBar`.

Comment: getting error on `getSupportActionBar();` and my imports are `import info.androidhive.tabsswipe.adapter.TabsPagerAdapter;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.ActionBar.Tab;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.widget.Toast;`

Comment: @AdnanMomin Try to use like this If you are using FragmentActivity   `ActionBar actionbar =((AppCompatActivity)getBaseContext()).getSupportActionBar();`

Comment: @AdnanMomin What is your Emulator Android API version? and also kindly post your logs while crashing. Will sort out the error easily.